# boost char_separator with digits

Tags: c++, boost

Can we use boost/tokenizer or boost::char_separator to separate with digits as well?

Let us say we have a line as :

```
1 *1:0 *2:0 0.01
```

We can break above line with delimiter, multiple delimiters with

```
boost::char_separator<char> space_star_sep{" ", ":"};
```

This will give me tokens as:

```
1
*1 
:
0
*2
:
0
0.01
```

If I use single delimiter as

```
boost::char_separator<char> space_star_sep{" "};
```

I will get:

```
1
*1:0
*2:0
0.01
```

Is there any way to break up the string by digits along with delimiters **directly**, instead of getting a token and parsing. Say, If I want tokens as:

```
1
*1
*2
0.01
```

I tried giving generic things in char_seperator such as \d et all but they are an unknown sequence for char separator.

Comment: Try `boost::char_separator<char> sep(": \f\n\r\t\v")`; and filter 0-s somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, can you tokenize the string by passing the delimiter string `":0"` into `char_seperator` or a similar function (let's say `strtok`)?

No.

By their intent, those functions only work by using a single character as the delimiter or tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two things here.

1. Tokenize on whitespace
2. Strip a trailing `:0` (or tokenize each token on `:` and get the first token)

Those are two operations, and will need to be performed as such.

Your `char_seperator` examples perform *one* tokenization, just with multiple candidate delimiters.

It sounds like your attempt is moving away from tokenisation and towards pattern matching, trying to extract subsequences of digits from the input string. That's fine (and may be a use case for regular expressions), though it doesn't match the sample output you've provided, since neither `*` nor `.` is a digit.

I would probably stick with the two-phase tokenisation, myself, though a regular expression for your use case may look a bit like this:

```
Pattern: /(\*)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?::0)?(?:\s+|$)/g

Input:   "1 *1:0 *2:0 0.01"

       | Captures:
       +-----+-------
Match: |  A  |  B
-------+-----+-------
 #1    |     |  1
 #2    |  *  |  1
 #3    |  *  |  2
 #4    |     |  0.01
```

#### ([live demo](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=106417))

*(Disclaimer: we don't know enough about the input syntax and about your expectations to guarantee that this is accurate.)*

I deliberately kept the `'*'` character in its own capture so that you can handle the numeric portion on its own without any further extraction from strings; that is, you could pass capture B to `std::stod` directly and use *capture A == "*"* as a boolean flag.